# Freeform: Is it possible to have custom email recipients

Tags: channel-entries, solspace-freeform, forms, email, notification

I have a channel called Jobs. When admin posts a new entry, they are presented with a field called `email_recipient` in which they can type an email address of their choice.

Then...on the template which contains the Freeform code. I would like to use the data in the `email_recipient` field to be used in the `admin_notify` parameter on Freeform. However, so far I have had no joy and wondered if this was even possible or will Freeform not allow this

Can anyone help me out with this?

My code is

```
{exp:channel:entries 
channel="jobs" 
dynamic="on" status="Open"
disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}

<h3>Job Application Form</h3>

{exp:freeform:form 
form_name="job_application" 
return="/contact/thanks" 
form:class="form-horizontal contact-form" 
form:id="job_application"
recipients="yes" 
recipient1="{recipient_email}"}

<!--Form Data-->

{/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Note that the above example is using `recipients="yes"` and `reciepient1=`. I have tried with `admin_notify` too with no difference

Comment: So you are trying to say that after put the code `recipient1="{recipient_email}"` It still not send email to that recipient?

Comment: Thats right. I have used a couple of emails to test but nothing has popped up in my inbox. The addresses are certainly correct so it has me a little baffled

Comment: Remove `recipients="yes" 
recipient1="{recipient_email}"}` and put `admin_notify="[your email address]"`. Put email hardcoded and test if you still not receive emails ?

Comment: Yes, hardcoding my gmail address and I've just had it sent through. Not sure why it can't recognise the custom field. I have used custom fields from the channel in the form data but the Freeform tag just doesn't seem to be processing it properly, if at all

Comment: under your `{exp:channel:entries}` pass parameter `parse="inward"` and mail will sent to `{recipient_email}` address :)

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you. It's just been sent using the custom field. Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Notifying parameter is working fine with Freeform. Issue is of **parsing**.

When we pass a EE loop under other EE loop, It will parse by priorities. In that case naturally Module tag will parse first and channel entries tag will parse after. You just need to tell `{exp:channel:entries}` to parse the loop first so your variable `{recipient_email}` will be available to use in **Freeform**.

Please add `parse="inward"` parameter to your `{exp:channel:entries}` loop and give it a try. :)